# What is the purpose of an "anti-pumping relay"?

Tags: motor, relay, high-voltage

A project I'm working on has another firm replacing the *anti-pumping relay* on a motor starter (4160 V, 500 hp). I've never heard of an anti-pumping relay and after googling it, I still don't understand the purpose. My summary is that it prevents a circuit breaker from 'hunting' and repetitive closures.

1. How does a circuit breaker 'hunt'?
2. How do repetitive circuit-breaker closures occur?
3. What does an *anti-pumping relay* do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to just read up on this at this link:
https://www.electrical4u.net/relay/anti-pumping-relay-diagram-and-working-function-explanation/

https://electricalfundaz.com/circuit-breaker-antipumping-device/

https://peguru.com/2012/03/power-circuit-breaker-operation-and-control-scheme/

But this is my interpretation of it things. Circuit breaker hunting is as follows:

1. If there is a fault and the breaker trips, it will be expected to
   trip against instantly if you try to close it right?
2. So suppose you have a button that you press to close the breaker. If you push this button to try and reset the breaker when there is still a fault on the line, it will instantly trip again, as it should.
3. But the breaker opens and closes very fast, and you are a slow human slowly pushing the button. This means the entire time you have the button depressed the breaker is furiously opening and closing. This is bad for the breaker.

---

There also seems to be another reason:

1. The circuit breaker has two coils in it: one to open/trip the breaker, and another to close it.
2. These coils are not designed for continuous duty and so will burn out if current is applied to them for too long (such as a slow human pressing a button to close the breaker).
3. It seems that the trip coil is automatically disconnected by the breaker itself whenever a trip occurs. However, the close coil is a problem since a slow human is slowly pushing a button to energize the close coil longer than necessary.

All this sounds like an electromechanical, power system equivalent of a level-triggered, non-retriggerable, astable (one-shot) timer.

---

Comment: I also found this article at [electrical engineering portal](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/anti-pumping-and-lockout-relays) that has some good explanations and graphics. I forgot that humans are really slow compared to electricity but your comparison to a one-shot timer is a useful visual.

Comment: @C.Lange I'm finding it difficult to figure out how the relay is actually wired though. The diagrams are all really confusing.

Comment: Figure 4 in the article I linked makes it look like the AP relay is wired as a latching relay requiring the button to open in order to reset. It's making sense to me now lol. This is how I'd program the PLC operation but I guess at this power level you need a hardware implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This Quora entry seems to explain this in detail. Here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-an-antipumping-relay

> a) How does a circuit breaker 'hunt'?

When the operator pushes the 'close' button, the breaker can cycle through multiple trip-and-resets while the operator is still pushing the button.

> b) How do repetitive circuit-breaker closures occur?

If there is a repeated fault trip (see above.)

> c) What does an anti-pumping relay do?

Conditions the button press to make one and only one attempt to close the breaker. If a fault occurs, the fault trip breaker will not be reset until the operator releases the button.  This interrupts the trip-and-reset loop.